# React native navigation error -TypeError: Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise, react-navigation

I rerouting user when proper data are loaded from Async Storage:

```
useEffect(() => {
        loadData(localStorageKeys.USER_LOGGED_IN, true)
            .then(isUserLoggedIn => {
                    if (isUserLoggedIn) {
                        props.navigation.navigate(NavigationLocations.DASHBOARD)
                            .catch(e => logNavigationError(e))
                    } else {
                        console.log("No user is signed in.");
                        console.log(AsyncStorage.getAllKeys());
                    }
                }
            )
            .catch(e => {
                console.error("Unable check locally if user is logged in.");
                debugger
                console.error(e);
            });
    }, []);
```

The routing works as intended, however I am getting this error:

```
index.js:1 Unable check locally if user is logged in.
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
(anonymous) @ Signup.js:32
Promise.catch (async)
(anonymous) @ Signup.js:29
...
```

Why is the error occuring even though the routing happens as intended?

Comment: Why you have written this line `.catch(e => logNavigationError(e))`

Comment: Because the navigation method returns a promise.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because `navigation.navigate` is not a Promise, and so it doesn't have the property `.catch`. If you want to catch an error here, instead use `try/catch`.

e.g.

```js
useEffect(() => {
        loadData(localStorageKeys.USER_LOGGED_IN, true)
            .then(isUserLoggedIn => {
                    if (isUserLoggedIn) {
                        try {
                            props.navigation.navigate(NavigationLocations.DASHBOARD);
                        } catch (e) {
                            logNavigationError(e);
                        }   
                    } else {
                        console.log("No user is signed in.");
                        console.log(AsyncStorage.getAllKeys());
                    }
                }
            )
            .catch(e => {
                console.error("Unable check locally if user is logged in.");
                debugger
                console.error(e);
            });
    }, []);
```

Comment: `navigate(url: string): Promise<WindowClient | null>;` - this means that there is a promise returned, unless I am mistaken?

Comment: That type comes from **firebase's** `navigate` method, not react router's.